# Retrieve list of places lang/lat in country

Tags: maps, gis

I want to retrieve a list containing hospital names, long/lat from mapping services like Google map..
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The google geocode API is the way to do this:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
```

to get a list i.e. for all hospitals in Oregon, USA you can use the following request:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=hospital,oregon,usa&sensor=false
```

This results in a long response with all information about a dozen hospitals.

There a various ways to modify the results.